# Single word for delaying an unpleasant task

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm looking for a single word that means delaying an unpleasant task, or perhaps delaying a task to the point in which delaying became unpleasant (or noticeably excessive).

`Postponing` is not a good word because it could simply mean rescheduling.

`Delaying` is also not a great term for what I'm looking for, since it doesn't imply anything necessarily unpleasant.

I think `dragging` has a similar vibe to what I'm looking for, but I can't use it since I haven't really started the task yet.

Comment: Can you provide a sample sentence to use it in?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The verb **procrastinate** / noun **procrastination** is an almost exact fit:

> **procrastinate** verb [ I ]
>
> to keep delaying something that must be done, often because it is
>   unpleasant or boring

[[Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/procrastinate)]

Note that this means 'delay/ing an unpleasant task'; it takes no object (the 'unpleasant task' is implied).

Comment: I would think this is what the OP had in mind especially since her first word was “postponing” which begins with a “p” and is similar in length of procrastinate. One thing I’m uncertain about with regards to the delaying is if she was talking about the decision not to perform the action, or if she was talking about delaying the task from anyone being able to perform it (as in sabotage or blocking). Given the examples, I’m still inclined to believe _procrastinate_ is the best choice.

Comment: While you correctly point out that it takes no object, it's easy to make a construction that clarifies what task is being delayed; e.g.: "I'm procrastinating on getting those TPS reports out." I'm not sure if it's proper English, but it's certainly widely used when the object is unclear.

Comment: I ended up using procrastinating. The fact that procrastinating doesn't take an object however, makes the emphasis on unpleasant/boring rather weak (in my opinion). Foot-dragging is a great term but it has the same problem; it describes the subject and not the object.

Answer (score 17):

Your instincts about "dragging" are correct; however, the term in actual use is

### foot-dragging

[Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/foot-dragging):

> Reluctance or deliberate delay concerning a decision or action.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foot-dragging):

> failure to act with the necessary promptness or vigor

There is an implication here that the person dragging their feet is under some obligation to do something or go somewhere, but is unwilling to do it. You can drag your feet even in taking an action to start your task.

Answer (score 9):

to **temporize**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/temporize)

> 1. To act or speak in order **to gain time, avoid an argument, or postpone a decision**

As in:

Facing an unpopular task, he temporized, hoping it would "go away".

Answer (score 7):

The following usage of ***[put  off](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/put-off)*** may convey the idea:

> to delay doing something, especially because you do not want to do it.
>
> - I was trying to put off the moment when I would have to leave.
>   You can’t put the decision off any longer.

(macmillandictionary.com)

Comment: How is "put off" single word?

Comment: @GreenAsJade with the magic of hyphenation, we can have "put-off" similar to  "put-down" or similar ?

Comment: A put-down is a thing.   A hyphenated noun.  However if I put off something that's a verb and an adverb ... I think!   I don't think that I put-off something, where that is a verb.

Comment: @GreenAsJade - consider “put off” as a single expression if that can make you feel better.

Comment: This is English, you can do anything you want, so long as it is clear.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stall](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/stall)

> delay or divert (someone/some task) by prevarication.
>
> - stall him until I'm finished.

---

### Second meaning

> (SAILING)  have insufficient wind power in the sails to give controlled motion.
>
> (MOTOR/ENGINE)  to have insufficient momentum to carry through a complete power cycle, to cease operation for lack of momentum.

So colloquially one might say *"I'm stalled on writing the job reference for young Mister Moosehead because I can't find the words to say how terrible a worker he is."*

Comment: Being 'stalled' is basically a passive thing, rather than a choice.